# Based on navigaton ,show/hide few controls in Angular

Tags: angular

I am going to Component **X** from two components **A,B**. If I go from **Component A** to **Component X** then I need to show/hide different set of controls whereas If  I go from **Component B** to **Component X** then I need to show/hide a different set of controls.
How can I achieve this,I can pass the query string parameter but it can be changed by the user in the browser.

How can I achieve this functionality in Angular 6?

I am setting a navigation link in component dynamically inside kendo grid

```
editHandler(dataItem) {

        this.router.navigate(['/A', dataItem.ID]);

  }
```

Comment: Did you try using BehaviorSubject? If not I think that would be good option for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

From your componentA and componentB you can pass parameter to determine from which component it's coming like :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Linkx', {state: "A"}]">Componenta </a>
<a [routerLink]="['/Linkx', {state: "B"}]">Componenta </a>
```

and in your x .ts you do:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.state = params['state']; // take the state
           // check the state and do your controls
    });
```

Comment: how to do this in Component?I have updated my current navigation code where I am setting navigation link dynamically inside kendo grid

Comment: are you using reactive form or template?